# Doctrine 2 query causes web page freeze

Tags: symfony, doctrine

When I try to run this query in my action controller, my browser page freezes:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences c WHERE c.locationid= ?1');
            $query->setParameter(1, 5);
            $id = $query->getResult();
```

But when I perform any other query like:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('SELECT c.title FROM Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences c WHERE c.locationid= ?1');
            $query->setParameter(1, 5);
            $id = $query->getResult();
```

everything seems to be in order. The only difference is that in the first one I retrieve whole object, not just single field.

This problem is happening for all tables, not just this one. What should I do?

Comment: What does the `Baza\BlogBundle\Entity\Conferences` entity look like? Does it have any relations to other entities?

Comment: I remember I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13913416/symfony2-controller-does-not-return-response-when-using-doctrine-query-builder) before within Symfony when using Doctrine Queries. likewise, I didn't have the issue when retrieving single fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unlikely the query is causing the hang, but rather what you do with the result after.  If you are ever 'printing' a symfony object, your browser will hang because of all the recursion.  Your second query fetches just the title, so you won't be printing the object, just a text field.

A simple fix would be to change the last line of your first query:

```
 $id = ($query->getResult())->getTitle();
```

(or whatever function make sense).  Would need to see more code if this does not solve the problem.